# Unable to open Jenkins localhost:8080

Tags: java

[image]

Kindly help me to resolve the issue as shown in the screenshot.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Please see the below. This will help you.

https://windowsreport.com/java-virtual-machine-fatal-error/

Comment: That error is displayed in the console because the command to get java version was entered in all caps.  As you can see, the second request was successful.

Answer (score 0):

First you should make sure that the Jenkins service is running on the machine.  Please try running services.msc to see if Jenkins appears in the list.  If it is running, you should be able to view using http://localhost:8080